# client 157.56.229.87 attempt to invoke directory as script: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

Tags: logging, hacking

Ok, so i frequently check my logs and see an array of errors logs from people "scoping the joint" but today i noticed a new one:

```
[client 157.56.229.87] attempt to invoke directory as script: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

This IP range had actually caused this error log a few times now but i cannot find out what it means..

I am assuming this is a hack attempt but does anyone know what they are trying to do and how to protect against it?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output you're seeing is typically related to the configuration you see here:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryAsScript

In this particular case, I don't think you have anything to worry about it - it looks like you have a directory aliased in the config, and the IP you provided is actually the MSN/Bing crawler, presumably crawling your site, and eventually hitting that aliased directory (worst case, you can robots.txt it out of that directory to prevent future errors).